# How do I import a .pst file into Outlook online?

Tags: email, outlook, exchange-server

How do I import a .pst file into Outlook online? I have downloaded a Outlook .pst file but I wish to view it on my Outlook online. How do I do that? If that is not possible, how can I convert that into a readable file such as text or pdf? thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not a programming question. That being said, open the PST file in Outlook (desktop client, not web), then Ctrl+drag (to copy) folders or messages to your Exchange mailbox.